# CSS class styles do not apply to elements when I upload code to my server

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a portfolio website, and I have some CSS class styles that work fine on my local machine (when I go to the files using file://) but when I upload them to my server (Ubuntu) the classes no longer apply.

For example:

I have this CSS class style.

```css
.header_home{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: x-large; 
  color: #b0e5f3;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

And it works just fine with this HTML code when it is running on my machine.

```html
<a href="index.html" class="header_home" style="grid-column: 1; grid-row: 1; background-color: #222322;">Home</a>
```

After looking at inspect element I can see in style editor that the site knows the class styles are there.

[Style Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4262.png)

And inspect element also tells me that it recognizes the element has a class.

[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XYyb.png)

But when I go to look at what styles are being applied, it is not inheriting the styles from the stylesheet.

[Applied Styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tehXA.png)

They should work because when I go to the html files using file:// in my browser I can see the styles being applied.

[Applied Styles Local Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1G9H.png)

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

*edit:*
I transferred the files to my server using scp if that helps.

*edit 2:*

I used this to link it to the page:

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Also, index.html and style.css are in the same directory so relative path should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your CSS file just isn't properly linked, or perhaps it isn't uploaded to the server? Can you show in your HTML file where you linked the CSS?

Perhaps the relative path to your CSS file has changed upon uploading? This is speculation but we can help if you give more information regarding the linking of the file & the document/folder structure.

Edit: Can you share a picture of the inspect element? Should show something like this, where you can see the applied class/style.
[image: screenshot_of_html_styles_applied]

Comment: I linked it using

```<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```,
and it is uploaded to the server.

index.html and style.css are in the same directory so relative path should be okay

Comment: Can you do a side-by-side comparison of my screenshot above & your inspected element?

Comment: I'm not sure how it fixed it but I just ran a system update and it works now. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: great! no worries.